# MonoGame.Extended.Content Extension can’t find SpriteFactory file

Tags: c#, io, monogame, sprite-sheet, monogame-extended

I am at a complete loss, there seems to be a stark lack of up-to-date documentation about how to load a spritesheet from SpriteFactory with the Extended Content.Load<>() extension. I have tried following all of the other posts on here about how to do it but whenever I do:

`var spriteSheet = Content.Load(“sheet.sf”, new JsonContentLoader());`

MonoGame constantly tells me it could not find the file, yet I have added it to the /Content directory and I can see it get converted to an .xnb in the build folder, so I am totally confused how it could be not finding the file.

I have added the necessary headers for Content, Sprites, and Serialization so this line should work yet for some reason Content can’t find the file. I have also already made sure I added a reference to the MonoGame.Extended.Content.Pipeline.dll in the Content.mgcb file so everthing is already setup it’s just getting Content to actually find the file.

Does anyone have any idea why it may not be able to find the file? I am on day 3 and my wife is already packing her bags I’ve complained so much about this.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried specifying the type for Sprite in the function? Example: `var spriteSheet = Content.Load<SpriteSheet>("sheet.sf", new JsonContentLoader());`

Comment: What is the actual error message? And where is the file relative to the build exe.